# Compact, sequential spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, ordinals

A compact, Hausdorff space  $X$ is *sequential* if each for each $A\subset X$ and $x\in \overline{A}$, there exists a countable set $A_0\subset A$ such that $x\in \overline{A}_0$.

I am asked to show that each sequential, compact Hausdorff space without isolated points of weight $\aleph_1$ contains a closed zero-dimensional subspace $X_0$ of weight $\aleph_1$.

Here's my attempt. let $\{U_\alpha\colon \alpha<\omega_1\}$ be a basis for $X$. Inductively choose a one-to-one trasnfinite sequence $x_\alpha$ such that $x_\alpha\in U_\alpha\setminus U_\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$. Is $X_0 = \overline{\{x_\alpha\colon \alpha<\omega_1\}}$ the right choice?

Comment: What if $U_1\subseteq U_0$? How do you choose $x_1$?

Comment: Good point. I guess that it would be enough to choose *just* some uncountable collection of points from distinct basic sets.

Comment: Your definition of _sequential_ is actually what is commonly called _countably tight_. Generally sequentiality is the condition that for every non-closed $A$ there is a sequence of points from $A$ which converges to a point outside of $A$. (Every sequential space is countably tight. It is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that the two notions are equivalent for compact Hausdorff spaces, but also consistent that they are different.)

Comment: Also, it's probably best just to ask a new question instead of drastically altering an old one.